# URL issue with JSONObject

Tags: java, json, simplejson

I've the following code, but when I am saving below JSON in database its giving me wrong url like `{"#url#":"https:\/\/www.test.com\/test"}`

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class DemoURL {
    private static String url = "https://www.test.com/test";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject msgJson = new JSONObject();
        msgJson.put("#url#", url);
        System.out.println(msgJson.toString());
    }
}
```

I want url like `{"#url#":"https://www.test.com/test"}`
**Please suggest how to fix it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
public class App{
    private static String url = "https://www.test.com/test";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject msgJson = new JSONObject();
        msgJson.put("#url#", url);
        System.out.println(getCleanURL(msgJson.toString()));
    }

    private static String getCleanURL(String url){
        return url.replaceAll("\\\\", "").trim();
    }
}
```

This gives correct output, simply run this code. This will store exact value in the database.

```
{"#url#":"https://www.test.com/test"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `org.json.simple` JSON library. JSON-Simple escapes char from String.
You can't change this thing, as its not configurable.

But you can use `org.json` JSON library, this will not escape String, and good part is, you don't have to change your code, existing syntax will work fine.

e.g.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class DemoURL {
    private static String url = "https://www.test.com/test";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject msgJson = new JSONObject();
        msgJson.put("#url#", url);
        System.out.println(msgJson.toString());
    }
}
```

output : `{"#url#":"https://www.test.com/test"}`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing slash(/) with unicode character \u2215 before passing it to JSON object.

Answer (score -1):

try to quote the string with single quotes, something like this

```
    JSONObject msgJson = new JSONObject();
    msgJson.put("#url#", "\'"+url+"\'");
    System.out.println(msgJson.toString());
```

Comment: No, its giving {"#url#":"'https:\/\/www.test.com\/test'"}, but I want  {"#url#":"https://www.test.com/test"}

Comment: try to fetch the url with Key as msgJson.get("#url#")

Comment: Nope, this way it works, but I want to set as a JSON keyValue pair